# Is there a WPF equivalent of Win2D.uwp CanvasControl?

Tags: c#, canvas, .net-4.7.2

The UWP CanvasControl has a great performance. It uses GPU rendering. Is there anything comparable for WPF .NET 4.7.2?

Comment: WPF are using DirectX if possible/allowed. DirectX using GPU if possible/allowed.

Comment: You mean I would get the same performance with a WPF Canvas control? Hmmm, I don't think so...

Comment: if the option to call winrt from wpf acceptable with you, you can follow the reference - https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/26/calling-windows-10-apis-from-your-wpf-application/